# In PHP, call/inject something in base php file from the included php file

Tags: php

Am new to PHP, so I might be totally off in my understanding, but am trying to see how to work the below out:

template.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        // Add a PHP 'Placeholder' here to inject some HTML if $filename = BodyInstance.php
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include($filename); // $filename = BodyInstance.php or can be any other php file  ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

BodyInstance.php

```
<p>
    This is a dummy body text
    <?php // Inject something into the placeholder of template.php ?>
</p>
```

So, I have a template.php file, which loads different views into the body depending upon the $filename parameter. Now, one of the views, BodyInstance.php needs to have some extra tags present in the head element. This needs to happen on the server side, I don't want to do it via jQuery on the client side on document.ready.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like a poor idea—I'm guessing you should rethink your idea somewhat—but you could do it by `include`ing a file there and checking against `__FILE__` to conditionally emit HTML.

Comment: Do away with the single quotes for starters... `'$filename'` will look for a file that is actually _called_ "$filename". Use no quotes at all, or pointless double quotes

Comment: why not add those *extra tags* in another file and `include` that second file in required page....will definitely save your from headache! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor: I could, but that would break my pattern and hence, consistency. template.php is a generic loader class and should be consistent across all the files it loads. At best (ideally), it should provide some placeholder overrides that can be overridden by the loaded class. That's the idea I have and i might be wrong, that's why seeking inputs here :)

Comment: @sppc42 : in that case before loading, detect the class using `get_class()` and then load accordingly based on `$filename` params...meaning if `get_class()` gives class which needs those extra tags and `$filename` has them...load it...makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the file based loading pattern for loading the tags based on the presence of a $filename-tags.php file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        // Add a PHP 'Placeholder' here to inject some HTML if $filename = BodyInstance.php
        <?php if (file_exists($filename ."-tags") include ($filename) ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include($filename); // $filename = BodyInstance.php or can be any other php file  ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is few options. But usually it's made using [`ob_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) functions:

```
[index.php]

ob_start(); // start Output Buffer
require "content.php"; // Will create $headerContent and returns some html.
$content = ob_get_contents(); // Get content from buffer
ob_end_clean(); // Clear buffer

require "baseHtml.php";

[content.php]

<?php $headerContent = '<style>body {background-color: red;}</style>'; ?>
<p>Some text here</p>

[baseHtml.php]

<html>
  <head>
     <?php echo $headerContent; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
     <?php echo $content; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Final output will be:

```
<html>
  <head>
     <style>body {background-color: red;}</style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <p>Some text here</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

This technique is usually used in CMS'es, because it allows to send headers after some content was "outputted" (only to buffer) and allows to preprocess content.

Comment: thanks, that looks like it'll do the trick. I was also thinking of having something like a include($filename."-tags") in template.php and load that only if it exists. Thus, BodyInstance.php can define another BodyInstance-tags.php, whilst other derived classes won't. Will try both these approaches today and repost which works the best. Thanks!

Comment: @sppc42 yes, you definitely have to apply dynamic file names, also lots of checks if file/variable exists before doing anything with them